# Unable to place the order - Invalid block type?

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, paypal-express

Recently my site have encountered a problem that some customers are not able to place order at the **Review Order** page.

The usual flow is like this: add products to cart --> view cart page --> one page check out --> PayPal page --> Review Order. Actually the last step is not necessary as long as the payment can go through successfully. But some products have got the problem that, right after the PayPal page, it turns to Review Order page and then when customers press "Place Order", nothing happens (and no payment is made). The admin then received an email saying that **Payment transaction failed** and "Unable to place the order".

What I mean by "some products" is that some other products do go through successfully. For example, when product "Red Umbrella" has encountered the aforementioned issue, then I duplicated the same product (with different SKU of course) and purchased it and there is no such error. (But I do not find anything unusual with the products themselves.)

I have checked the exception.log at var/log and it shows something strange:

> 2016-03-27T16:52:58+00:00 ERR (3):  exception 'Mage_Core_Exception'
>   with message 'Invalid block type:
>   Mage_Braintree_Payments_Block_Datajs' in
>   /home/public_html/uk/app/Mage.php:595

......

> 2016-03-27T16:52:58+00:00 ERR (3):  exception 'Mage_Core_Exception'
>   with message 'Invalid block type: Mage_Braintree_Payments_Block_Form'
>   in /home/public_html/uk/app/Mage.php:595

I have tried to allow these blocks (at System --> Permission --> Blocks) but with no luck.

> opc/braintree_form
>
> opc/braintree_datajs
>
> braintree_payments/datajs
>
> braintree_payments/form

I am using the IWD One Page Check Out extension and it used to be fine (at least for the past two months). So I think it is not about a conflict of extension.

Anyway, I then tried to look into iwd_opc.xml and only found that the braintree stuff is under "PAYPAL EXPRESS LIGHTBOX" and I do not think there is any unusual here as well.
I am not using this extension but I have tried to find an solution from their answer. But it doesn't help I am afraid: http://store.lotusbreath.com/review/product/view/id/13/.

I am almost burned out with this issue (customers have enter their credit card info but they cannot place order and they think it is somehow a scam - even though no payment has been gone through)! Would be really appreciate if any master can help! Thank you very much!

P.S. I am using Magento 1.9.2.2 and the payment method is PayPal Express.

Comment: Please share the (opc/braintree )EXTENSION_LAYOUT.xml  code here